# Parsing input properties in a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I feel like I am running out of ideas on how to solve this issue.

So I have a component that should read a file and display some data from that file. I want to pass only the filename to component so that it can handle reading and parsing the file. To do this I added a property to the component.

The issue I seem to have is that I can't really access that property from the `data` function, and if I add a watcher on the property I can parse the file as expected, but I can't seem to get that data into the DOM.

This is what I have right now:

```
<template>
  <main :key="fileName">
    fileName: {{fileName}}
    <div class="post">{{data}}</div>
    <div class="info">
      <div v-for="item in info" v-bind:key="item.name">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
const { parse } = require("@/service/parser");
const fs = require("fs");
let postInfo = { data: "abc", info: [] };
export default {
  props: ["fileName"],
  watch: {
    fileName: {
      immediate: true,
      handler: (newVal, oldVal) => {
        if (newVal) {
          postInfo = parse(
            fs
              .readFileSync(__dirname + "/../../assets/" + newVal, "utf8")
              .split("\n")
          );
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data: () => {
    return postInfo;
  }
};
</script>
```

I am obviously completely new to Vue, and I'm probably missing something stupid here.

So what am I doing wrong and how do I get the parsed data into my DOM?

Comment: You're assigning a new value to the (external to Vue) variable `postInfo` instead of to `this.postInfo`. You _should_ be able to use `this.fileName` in your `data` function.

Comment: That is one thing that has me quite confused. I have read a lot of posts where people use `this.whatever` in their data function. For me `this` is undefined (god knows why), so if I for example run `console.log(this.fileName)` then I will get an error saying that I cannot read `fileName` from `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an arrow function for your `data` function. Arrow functions bind `this` to whatever context the function is declared in. You need to let Vue properly bind `this` to the instance it is creating. So use

```
data() {
  return postInfo;
}
```

or if for some reason you need to be old school:

```
data: function () {
  return postInfo;
}
```